# Expo SDK 44 upgrade ERROR - App.js: [BABEL]: Unexpected token '.'

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, babeljs

I have recently upgraded my app from SDK 40 to SDK 44 and came across this error App.js: [BABEL]: Unexpected token '.' (While processing: /Users/user/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-preset-expo/index.js)

Error Stack Trace:

```
App.js: [BABEL]: Unexpected token '.' (While processing: /Users/user/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-preset-expo/index.js)
/Users/user/path/to/project/node_modules/babel-preset-expo/index.js:48
        ...(options?.jsxRuntime !== 'classic' && {
                    ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at loadCjsDefault (/Users/user/path/to/project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js:85:18)
    at loadCjsOrMjsDefault (/Users/user/path/to/project/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/module-types.js:57:16)
```

Here is my babel.config.js:

```
return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo', { jsxRuntime: 'automatic' }],
    plugins: [
        ['inline-dotenv'],
        ['.....']
    ]
}
```

Here is my package.json:

```
{
    "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "expo start",
        "android": "expo start --android",
        "ios": "expo start --ios",
        "web": "expo start --web",
        "eject": "expo eject",
        "test": "jest"
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "jest-expo"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.16.5",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "~1.15.0",
        "@react-native-community/art": "^1.2.0",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "4.0.0",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.10",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "7.1.3",
        "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.2.2",
        "@react-native-community/slider": "4.1.12",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.4",
        "aws-amplify": "^3.3.1",
        "aws-amplify-react-native": "^4.2.6",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "expo": "^44.0.0",
        "expo-app-loading": "~1.3.0",
        "expo-barcode-scanner": "~11.2.0",
        "expo-camera": "~12.1.0",
        "expo-constants": "~13.0.0",
        "expo-font": "~10.0.4",
        "expo-linking": "~3.0.0",
        "expo-mail-composer": "~11.1.0",
        "expo-notifications": "~0.14.0",
        "expo-permissions": "~13.1.0",
        "expo-secure-store": "~11.1.0",
        "expo-sqlite": "~10.1.0",
        "expo-updates": "~0.11.2",
        "expo-web-browser": "~10.1.0",
        "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
        "jsbarcode": "^3.11.3",
        "link": "^0.1.5",
        "metro-config": "^0.64.0",
        "npm": "^8.3.0",
        "qs": "^6.9.4",
        "react": "17.0.1",
        "react-dom": "17.0.1",
        "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-44.0.0.tar.gz",
        "react-native-barcode-expo": "^1.1.1",
        "react-native-elements": "^3.2.0",
        "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.1.0",
        "react-native-modal": "^11.5.6",
        "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.6.0",
        "react-native-paper": "^3.10.1",
        "react-native-push-notification": "^3.5.2",
        "react-native-reanimated": "~2.3.1",
        "react-native-router-flux": "^4.2.0",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
        "react-native-screens": "~3.10.1",
        "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
        "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
        "react-native-web": "0.17.1",
        "react-navigation-animated-switch": "^0.6.4",
        "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.4.11",
        "react-navigation-header-buttons": "^3.0.5",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.0.0-alpha.3",
        "yarn": "^1.22.17"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
        "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.6.0",
        "babel-preset-expo": "9.0.1",
        "eslint": "^6.8.0",
        "expo-cli": "^5.0.2",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "jest-expo": "^44.0.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.66.2",
        "react-test-renderer": "^16.13.1"
    },
    "private": true
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please post text instead of pictures of text.

Comment: Added the error stack trace as a text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you give your

- package.json
- node version

I think that's because of the babel issue / your node version, because it cannot transpile the optional chaining https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

maybe tried using latest LTS node version? because as far as I know, the latest LTS node version already support optional chaining

Comment: My node version is v12.19.0

Comment: @ShahryarFaraji tried to using node version 16.x It's natively already support optional chaining

Comment: I installed the latest 16.x but when I'm doing npm install it gives me an Unsupported engine.

Comment: does your package.json have "node" defined in there? can you removed it?

Comment: No. I even removed the node_modules folder and package-lock to install fresh. But now when I type "npm install", I get error.

Comment: This is the error when I'm trying to install npm - https://ibb.co/6gb86NJ

Comment: Can you tried to run `npm install --legacy-peer-deps` ?

Comment: All good. But it says "Finished building JavaScript bundle in 80793ms." and stays in the initial screen and nothing else, anything to do with the node version here as well?

Comment: Never mind that first issue fixed. This new one is an internal issue.
Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

Just to let you know, it's a bug in `babel-preset-expo` when you are using Node 12.

> Optional chainning is not supported in node12 and can be easily replaced with extra checks

https://github.com/expo/expo/pull/15545

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, Expo SDK 44 is still in beta.

The Error Stack Trace reads that newer syntax **(in this case the optional chaining operator ?.)** isn't being transpiled by Babel which causes the failure.

Simply downgrading to the stable SDK 43 should solve all issues.

P.S: This error has been reported to Expo already by the beta testers.

Answer (score 1):

If you use expo v44 you have to update *babel-preset-expo* dev dependency to v9.0.2:

```
"babel-preset-expo": "9.0.2",
```

Answer (score -2):

Downgrading to SDK 43.0.0 worked fine for me:

```
expo update 43.0.0
```